# add the directory containing `cairo-gobject.pc'

Tags: python, python-3.x, cairo, pkg-config, pycairo

I'm trying to install PyGObject on a RH Linux system, using the command

```
    python3 /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 install PyGObject
```

But it dies with the ff. error msg:

```
    Package cairo-gobject was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo-gobject.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

I *think* the cairo-gobject should already have been installed, and I would gladly tell pip where to look for `cairo-gobject.pc`--if only I knew.  But I don't have a clue where it is.

I'm generally following the instructions for [installing PyGObject on Fedora systems](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#fedora-getting-started), although a lot of things seem to have changed since that write-up.  For example, using `yum` instead of `dnf`.  Also, following the instructions, I initially did

```
    yum install cairo-devel
```

But `yum search` revealed that there are actually two such packages: cairo-devel.i686 and cairo-devel.x86_64.  It's not clear to me which one was actually installed, nor whether yum automagically selects the right one.

And while our system interprets `python` as `python2`, we also have `python3` installed, and we need to use this program I'm trying to install with v3.  So instructions for calling `pip`, `python` etc. need to be modified to use Python3.  I *think* I've done that everywhere, although it's of course possible that I goofed, and cairo-gobject is somewhere that only P2 knows.

Packages I've installed: gcc, gobject_introspection-devel, cairo-devel, pkg-config, python3-devel, python36-devel, python36-setuptools, gtk3, pycairo.  But still, when I try to do

```
    python3 /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 install PyGObject
```

it dies (as I said above) with `Package cairo-gobject was not found in the pkg-config search path.`

What lack I yet?  Where might I look for this `cairo-gobject.pc` thing?  I know that cairo.pc is under /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/, but cairo-gobject.pc is nowhere under /usr/.  Where else might it be?

Last Minute: While making sure I'd dotted every 'i' before posting, I noticed a 't' I'd forgotten to cross, namely a msg I'd overlooked while trying to install PyGObject:

```
    Building wheel for PyGObject (PEP 517) ... error
```

But the build goes on past that error (that's my excuse for missing it before), until it finally quits with the above-referenced message about cairo-gobject.pc.  There's some discussion about this PEP517-related issue [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6222), but I don't see a resolution.  Or if there is, I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: I have no clue, basically, but Google suggests that the package you need is actually called cairo-gobject-devel.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not in the office today, but i'll give that a shot.  Fwiw, I find it appalling that these things are so hard to build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue -- indeed, cairo-gobject-devel does it, as Uli suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> Many distributions including Debian, Fedora, and others regularly include recent versions of cairo. As more and more applications depend on cairo, you might find that the library is already installed. To get the header files installed as well may require asking for a -dev or -devel package as follows:
>
> For Debian and Debian derivatives including Ubuntu:
>
> ```bash
> sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
> ```
>
> For Fedora:
>
> ```bash
> sudo yum install cairo-devel
> ```
>
> For openSUSE:
>
> ```bash
> zypper install cairo-devel
> ```

Source: https://www.cairographics.org/download/

Comment: Thanks--my original post was from so long ago that I don't even remember why I was doing this, and we certainly don't have that computer any more.  Still, this issue--or a similar one--may come up again, I hope I remember your comment ("may require asking for a -dev or -devel package") when it does.  It ought to be easier, IMNSHO.